How to reduce drag-and-drop delay in ReorderableListView within a Streambuilder?
I have a page that displays a list of journeys in a certain order. Previously, I displayed these journeys through a ListView inside a StreamBuilder that listens to an ordered select query from my local Drift database. I want it to be a StreamBuilder because each journey is editable and I want the list to display the recent change when a journey gets updated. However, when changing the ListView to a ReorderableListView and updating order of the journeys through database operations there is a slight lag where the tile jumps back to the original position and then updates properly. This doesn't look nice, and I understand that updating through the database rather than the state is not the best idea. What would be the best way to manage this problem so that I have reactive UI based on an edit to a journey, but don't have to talk to the database while reordering the items (so maybe only sending the updated order to the database on save)? Could the provider package be of help?
There's quite a lot of code involved here so I won't include it all but I have included a screenshot which hopefully makes it a bit easier to understand.

My current onReorder function (I'm aware there are some indexing issues, I can fix those later):
onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {
    // Ranks that need to be incremented by one
    final incrementRanks = [
        for (var i = min(oldIndex, newIndex) + 1;
            i <= max(oldIndex, newIndex) - 1;
            i++)
            i
    ];

    // Id of item being moved
    final movedId = snapshot.data![oldIndex].id;

    // Ids of items that need to be incremented
    final incrementIdList = snapshot.data!
        .sublist(min(oldIndex, newIndex) + 1,
            max(oldIndex, newIndex))
        .map((stage) => stage.id)
        .toList();

    tourService.updateStageRank(newIndex, movedId!);
    incrementRanks.asMap().forEach((index, rank) {
        tourService.updateStageRank(
            rank + 1, incrementIdList[index]!);
    });
}

EDIT:
The stream in the StreamBuilder is the following function
Stream<List<Stage>> getStagesStream(String tourId) {
    return localDatabase.tourDao.getStages(tourId).watch();
  }

which watches the following SQL function in my local Drift database
getStages: SELECT * FROM Stages
           WHERE tour_id = :tour_id
           ORDER BY rank;


Show me the "stream:" parameter of your StreamBuilder.  I bet it's performing a calculation and recreating the stream on each rebuild.

@RandalSchwartz I've added some more information!

Yup.  Classic mistake.  Watch this: https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg

@RandalSchwartz I might remember reading something like this on a Flutter best practices blog . I will see if I can fix it with this and otherwise come back to plead some more :). Thanks!

I don't know if it'll fix your problem, but it's a low-hanging fruit, and those should be picked early.

@RandalSchwartz unfortunately the hop back original position before moving to the new position is still there :/. I think it has to do with the fact that I'm getting the order by first updating it in the database which causes a delay with the stream picking up on that change. Not sure how manage it within the state though without also the view on edit to an item
